# validating for a date in a grails app

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

My domain class has a date field. I'm getting data from the user in the format "mm/dd/yyyy"

So in my `save()` method in the controller I did this:

```
def save1() {
    Date eventDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(params.eventDate)
    def event = eventService.addEvent(eventDate, "test")
    if (event.hasErrors())
        render(view:  "create", model: [eventInstace: event])
    else {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: ['Event', event.id])}"
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
}
```

So if the the user doesn't enter anything in the date field of the form or enters an invalid date, my code is reading at this line:

```
Date eventDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(params.eventDate)
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params.date("eventDate", "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Will return null instead of throwing an exception.